# word-request: need some vocab for a priority levels table

Tags: word-request

> **Priority levels**
>   4 | critical | Must be done as soon as possible
>   3 | high     | Should be done
>   2 | medium   | Include if there is still a space in the list
>   1 | low      | Don't bother including at this moment

There are three columns in the table (looks kind of ugly, but it's because that no matter how many spaces I use, it defaults to just one space when rendered). The first column contains numbers each of which stands for a particular priority level. The second column has the textual representations of the numbers. The third column contains a short description for each priority level in the table.

My question is what names would you give to each column in this table so that it looks professional?

Thank you.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Is it a table? Could you put some images of what you have to deal with?

Comment: Number, Name, Description?

Comment: It's not just a number and it's not just a name. Description might work though.

Comment: You gotta admit, it's pretty hard to imagine what you mean that easily. You don't give pictures, examples or anything.

Comment: Imagine a spreadsheet table. Horizontally it has rows that have data in them and vertically columns. Each line in my example above is a row. And I need to give professionally-sounding names to the columns. That's all.

Comment: You might want to ask in some database-oriented Stack Exchange community - either directly or in a chat.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://feww.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/aqi-health-chart.png For a wider variety, look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=emergency+levels&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Or7cVIjLF4aoyQTAt4DwDA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1111&bih=770#imgdii=oq6m79byNdPmYM%3A%3BDbfME_i9DLI0qM%3Boq6m79byNdPmYM%3A&imgrc=oq6m79byNdPmYM%253A%3Bk9zkQln35UrKIM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Ffeww.files.wordpress.com%252F2011%252F06%252Faqi-health-chart.png%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Ffeww.wordpress.com%252Ftag%252Fbeijing-smog%252F%3B604%3B421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you actually have three categories here: you actually have two categories, one of which is divided into two subcategories, but there are two ways to do that division.  One way is that the first two columns are both "levels", one expressed as numbers and the other as words, and the third column is a "description".  The other way is to think of the first column as "level", with the second and third as "descriptions", with the second as a short description and the third as an expanded description.  Point being, I would only use two labels (I'm assuming this is possible in your table):  "Level" and "Description".  Either "Level" goes over column 1 and column 2 together, or "Description" goes over column 2 and column 3 together.

You could spell it out (**Level Number | Level Name | Description**) but what's the point? The fact that one is numbers and one is a name is obvious from the context.

Answer (score 3):

These are some of the ones I came up with just now, try different combinations of the words below.

| **Level** | **Urgency** | **Status** |

| **Level | Status | Urgency** |

| **Scale | Weight | Hurry** |

| **Level | Importance | Hurry** |

I go with **level** and **scale** for the column with the numbers because they're commonly associated with numeric values.